# Getting error in manipulating shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want that the disclaimer should come 1st time after installing my app !
For that in my MainActivity I have make 2 buttons : 1st 'agree' button will store boolean 'true' vale in the Shared Preference & will redirect it to u in the Welcome.class ! And the second button will terminate the app !
This condition should come the first time after installing the app !
I am not able to find my mistake !?!

MainActivity.java code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener    
    {public static String filename = "MySharedString";
SharedPreferences settings;
Button agree,disagree;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state)
{
    super.onCreate(state);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    text2.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Button agreeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button disagreeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    agreeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    disagreeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    settings = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1:
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        boolean agreement = settings.getBoolean("agreement",false);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("agreement", true);
        editor.commit();

        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class);
                    startActivity(i);
        break;

         case R.id.button2:
             finish();
             System.exit(0);
         }
     }
}
```

activity_main.xml code :

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#d3d3d3"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Disclaimer" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="This is a Disclaimer."
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt1"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="DisAgree" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
    android:text="Agree" />

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Welcome.java code :

```
    public class Welcome extends Activity
    {
      @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
             TextView iv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

     }
}
```

welcome.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="WELCOME !"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.disclaimer1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.disclaimer1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.example.disclaimer1.Welcome"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

LOGCAT :

10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable   to find explicit activity class {com.example.disclaimer1/com.example.disclaimer1.Welcome}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at com.example.disclaimer1.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:54)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-13 07:23:30.069: E/AndroidRuntime(3356):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: so now whats happening?

Comment: why are you using getApplicationContext() for starting activity?

Comment: What is the error you are experiencing? You say you get error but do not say what it is.

Comment: The error is in the onClick of case 1st method 
case R.id.button1:

Comment: Some code is missing in that case , don't know how to resolve it !

Comment: @Vivart This is because i want to start the next activity if agree is clicked !

Comment: You have set the value after getting it in your sharepreference that is why you are not able to get it i guess.

Comment: the app is running smoothly but i want that after clicking agree button i go back and open the disclaimer1 again ! there should only be the welcome screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you declare your **Welcome** activity in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

**Final Answer**

Ok, this isn't the most elegant way to do this, but it'll get ya started. Afterward, I'd suggest you investigate Ok/Cancel dialogs with long text, and use one of those instead of having two activities.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{ 
    public static String filename = "MySharedString"; 
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile"; 

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) 
{ 
    super.onCreate(state); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 

    TextView text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1); 
    TextView text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    text2.setText("Android custom dialog example!"); 

    ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); 

    Button agreeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button disagreeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    agreeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    disagreeButton.setOnClickListener(this); 

    boolean agree = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0).getBoolean("agreement", false);
    if(agree)
    {
        openWelcome();
    }           
}

@Override 
public void onClick(View v) 
{ 
    switch (v.getId()) 
    { 
        case R.id.button1: 
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);             
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit(); 

            editor.putBoolean("agreement", true); 
            editor.commit();        

            openWelcome();

            break; 

        case R.id.button2: 
            finish(); 
    }
}

private void openWelcome()
{
    Intent i=new Intent(this, Welcome.class);
    startActivity(i);

    finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: ya i just declared it in manifest by this line :
<activity android:name="com.example.Welcome"></activity>
then also it is showing the same error

Comment: ERROR : 10-13 07:17:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3313): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.disclaimer1/com.example.disclaimer1.Welcome}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
10-13 07:17:35.639: E/AndroidRuntime(3313):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: also included full package name'

Comment: ya it is in right directory i checked it in going through workspace

Comment: both the java files are in src/com/example/disclaimer1

Comment: ya i restarted also , ,,, but the problem persists the same

Comment: wow that worked !! thanks .... !
the problem was that i was using uppercase in me package name , which was giving the yellow mark which i ignored !

Comment: the app is running smoothly but i want that after clicking agree button i go back and open the disclaimer1 again  ! there shoulg only be the welcome screen

Answer (score 0):

Its just that you first have to set the value for in `Sharedpreference and then after only you can access it.

Try as below:

```
 switch (v.getId())
    { 
    case R.id.button1:
        //Add the value in Sharepreference
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("agreement", true);
        editor.commit();

          //Get the value from it. 
          SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        boolean agreement = settings.getBoolean("agreement",false);

        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class);
                    startActivity(i);
        break;
     }
```

Comment: the app is running smoothly but i want that after clicking agree button i go back and open the disclaimer1 again ! there shoulg only be the welcome screen

Answer (score 0):

You don't get value from sharedprefs before assign value. You didn't assign value to "agreement" variable, how can you get value from it ? It would be like this;

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.button1:
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("agreement", true);
        editor.commit();

        //now you can get value of agreement
    boolean agreement = settings.getBoolean("agreement",false);


        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class);
                    startActivity(i);
        break;

         case R.id.button2:
             finish();
             System.exit(0);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: ok, the app is running smoothly but i want that after clicking agree button i go back and open the disclaimer1 again ! there should only be the welcome screen