# How can I set button globally so I can edit the properties when I'm in another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

What I want is:

- When I click the button at the page 2, the visibility of `button1` in the page 1 will be set to true (`setVisibility(true)`).
- Or, I want a save point so that after I go to the page 2, when my cp restart, it will go directly to page 2, skipping page 1.

First page

```
public class FirstpageActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.firstpage);
        final Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chp1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(FirstpageActivity.this, Secondform.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.firstpage, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Second page

```
public class Secondform extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondform);
        final Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Secondform.this, Thirdform.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.secondform, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I edited the post to make your question clearer. If there's any mistake, feel free to edit and correct them.

Comment: sir can you help me about this i need badly :(

Comment: @Warde I assumed it's the app: *if the app is restarted, ...*. However, I didn't correct it since I'm not sure myself.

Comment: You need to implement shared preferences by setting a boolean variable !google it

Comment: @AndrewT. yes its the app when restarted

Comment: @Warde. can you show me some code im new to programming and its for my project please :(

Comment: @MheljunNewbie see the problem here & its solution ! Similar to ur issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343635/getting-error-in-manipulating-shared-preferences

Comment: yes also your question is not clear, this is why you dont get answers

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the initial state of your Button in `FirstPageActivity` is set to Invisible.

So, in order to store global definitions you can use `SharedPrefrences`.

In your `FirstpageActivity`, inside `onCreate()` method,  use this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // "0" is for private mode

Boolean btn = pref.getBoolean("btnState", null); //Checking if value exists
if (btn==null){
//No value exists
} else if (btn) { //checking if btn is true
bt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else { //if false
bt1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Now, in your `Secondform` activity, in your Button method where you want to change visibility of `FirstpageActivity` Button, add as follows:

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("btnState", true); //to make the button visible
//editor.putBoolean("btnState", false); //to make the button invisible
editor.commit();
```

That's it, you are done.
Once you understand how this works you can implement it any way you want.

Hope this helps!